# UITableView Grouped Arrays

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I cannot seem to logically figure out how to have a separate array for each grouped section that would each show different data in the detailed view of a navigation controller.  For each group, there is different data, but there the second view currently displays data in a UILabel from one array and starts at the beginning of the array for each group.  Please let me know if you need more information.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Keeping of Business Names for Detailed View
    addressBook=@[@"Clinic 1 Business",@"Clinic 2 Business",@"Clinic 3 Business"];

    //holding of clinic names per county
    adams=@[@"Clinic 1 Business Listing",@"Clinic 2 Business Listing",@"eeeee"];
    allegheny=@[@"Clinic 3 Business Listing",@"Clinic 4 Business Listing"];
    armstrong=@[@"Clinic 5 Business Listing",@"Clinic 6 Business Listing",@"Clinic 7 Business Listing"];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;


    NSLog(@"this is the content of addressBook: \n %@", addressBook);

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 3;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return addressBook.count;
    if(section==0)
    {
        return [adams count];
    }
    else if(section==1)
    {
        return [allegheny count];
    }
    else if (section==2)
    {
        return [armstrong count];
    }
}

/*
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rec", @"A", @"B", nil ];
}
*/

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"abCell";
    addressBookCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        cell.addressBookLbl.text=[adams objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else if(indexPath.section==1)
    {
        cell.addressBookLbl.text=[allegheny objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if (indexPath.section==2)
    {
        cell.addressBookLbl.text=[armstrong objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"addressBookDetails"]) {

        addressBookDetailsViewController *addressDetailsController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *abIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        int row = [abIndexPath row];

        addressDetailsController.addressDetail=@[addressBook[row]];

        NSLog(@"this is the content of addressBook: \n %@", addressBook);
    }
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
        return @"Adams County";
    }
    else if(section==1)
    {
        return @"Allegheny County";
    }
    else if(section==2)
    {
        return @"Armstrong County";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. You explain the problem, but not the ideal scene.

Comment: The ideal goal is to display different data in the detailed view for each section in the table.

Comment: What is in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Nothing, I am not sure what to do with it.

Comment: :O. Well, my friend, that how you will pass your data along! How do you call addressBookDetails segue? Is it connected to the prototype cell?

Comment: Yes, it is connected to the prototype cell.

Comment: Add an edit to your question and post the NSLog of addressBook. so `NSLog(@"this is the content of addressBook: \n %@", addressBook);`

Comment: I tried that and data did not show up in the log.

Comment: This is using the segue so it cannot use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Nay, my friend. You can and will use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (trust me). Put the log in `viewDidLoad` after you create the addressBook array. If you get nothing, then your array is not being created correctly. Bear with me, I'm almost done writing my answer, but I need the data.

Comment: You're correct, the data is not showing up in viewDidLoad.  See my update.

Comment: OK. You figure out why the Array is empty, and I'll figure out how to send the data along.

Comment: The array is not empty because it shows up fine in the next scene, but it did not show up in NSLog for some reason.

Comment: Which next scene? I thought you couldn't get it to the next scene?

Comment: Did you get my answer? Did you try it out?

Comment: I will try it out later tonight, I was at work.  Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37069/discussion-between-klinetel-and-captjak)

Comment: OK. Waiting in chat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you would pass data along would be by using a segue, which is what you are doing. The thing that you are not doing correctly is in the `prepareForSegue` method. Just to simplify things, use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, so you aren't creating your own way of finding the selected cell.

To handle that, you will have to add a little to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Here is what you need to do:

The:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

method that you have, should look like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addressBookDetails"]) {

        addressBookDetailsViewController *addressDetailsController = [segue destinationViewController];

        addressDetailsController.addressDetail = selectedAddressBook;
       //selectedAddressBook is an array that you don't have yet, but will create in the next step
       //Make sure that the addressDetail in the DetailViewController is an Array, and not something else

    }
}
```

Now you want to create the array `selectedAddressBook`. So in the header (we're still in the MasterViewController):

```
@interface  //blah blah blah
{
    NSArray *selectedAddressBook;
}
```

OK, now back to the implementation file (still MasterViewController). Now you are going to use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method (I'll give an explanation on the importance of this at the end).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //some animation to fade away the blue on selection
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    //here you will populate the array that you created
    selectedAddressBook = (NSArray *)addressBook[indexPath.row];

    //now you perform your segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addressBookDetails" sender:self];
}
```

If you try and run it now, it will probably crash. Remove the existing segue. Just delete it. Create a new segue between the MasterViewController itself and the DetailViewController. Select whatever type you want, but you should probably use the `Replace` segue. Give that segue the same identifier as the one you just deleted.

Now, in the DetailViewController .m file put an NSLog to watch for data in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Did the array get passed along? Let's see :\n %@", addressDetail);
    //addressDetail should be the name of the array in this VC
}
```

If all went well, then the Log should show the details ONLY for the row that was selected. Now in the DetailViewController, you can access the data from the array and display it however you want to.

The reason you need to yu the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method when using a tableView, is really just because is makes life simple. This method recognizes the row that was selected, by using NSIndexPath. Which does away with the way you were watching it in your `prepareForSegue` method. ***It tells the delegate that the specified row is now selected.*** Using that, you can selectively perform actions on cell taps.

Comment: How do you "Replace" the segue?

Comment: @Klinetel, the 'Replace' segue is a segue type. Delete the current one Ctrl+click drag to the next view, a pop-up will come along. Select "replace".

Comment: No luck, I do not see what you mean.  I even looked on Google without finding an answer.

Comment: I tried exactly what you explained without the replace segue (just created a new one) and now it crashes when I select a table row...

Comment: Which segue did you use and what does the crash say @Klinetel?

Comment: I got it to actually display some data now, but when I click the back button on top toolbar it repeats the scene and I have to click twice to get back to the original table.  Then the data will never display again.  Would it be more helpful to email this code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what you are trying to do with the `addressBook` array you have above. The rest, looks like you should use a dictionary for. Are you familiar with dictionaries? You could set the key to the county and the value to array for that county. Then when you are asking for `numberOfSectionsInTableView` you `return [myDictionary allKeys].count`

Let me know if that makes sense. If not, I'll elaborate further. Also, describe what the purpose of `addressBook` is.

Comment: I am not too familiar with dictionaries.  Please explain further.  addressBook is just an array to hold business names to be displayed in the detailed view.

Comment: You should use NSDictionnary (hashtable if you prefer : [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table]))

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this with a dictionary.